# change count value under condition in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT I have the following xml file (pets.xml)

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href = "pets.xsl"?>
<stores>
<store>
<animal kind="cat">cat</animal>
<animal kind="dog">dog</animal>
<animal kind="bird">bird</animal>
</store>
<store>
<animal kind="cat">cat</animal>
<animal kind="bird">bird</animal>
</store>
<store>
<animal kind="dog">dog</animal>
<animal kind="bird">bird</animal>
</store>
</stores>
```

what I need to do is to generate an html page that contains a table displaying how many pet stores have a certain kind of animal so the result should be

```
-------------------
|animal| nb stores|
-------------------
|cat   |   2      |
-------------------
|dog   |   2      |
-------------------
|bird  |   3      |
-------------------
```

What I did in XSLT is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "2.0" 
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
<xsl:template match= "/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>animal</td>
<td>nb stores</td>
</tr>
<xsl:variable name="count" select="0"/>
<xsl:for-each select="stores/store/animal">
<xsl:variable name="an" select="@kind"/>
<!--<xsl:for-each select="stores/store/animal">
<xsl:variable name="newan" select="@kind"/>
<xsl:when test = "$newan=$an">
<xsl:variable name="count" select="$count+1"/>
</xsl:when>-->
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="$an"/>
</td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the part that is commented is to increment the counter every time i find a store that have the animal that is placed in the variable an
but it gave problems so I commented it and now all I get is a table listing the types of animal and under nb stores I have all zeros.
If you could tell me how I can change the count variable when the condition is met.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Variables are "immutable" in XSLT, which means they cannot be changed once set. The problem you have here is actually a "grouping" problem. If you can use XSLT 2.0 then the command to use here is `xsl:for-each-group`. Check out http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html as an example.

Comment: Thanks it's a helpful article